# How to fill div background color to full browser height without distorting mobile view using CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my div element bg color to cover 100% height of my browser to cover over my bg img:

Chrome Full Browser View

Now I have tried height: 100% for my HTML selector, which worked but at the cost of my mobile view:

Mobile View

I've also tried 100vh but it has the same result.
Right now I seem to be stuck with one or the other.

CSS

```
*{
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   color: white;}

a:link{
  color: white;
 }

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-image: url(../portfolio/images/bg-img1.jpeg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container-shader{
  background-color: rgba(54,54,56,0.8);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }

.btn{
  border-style: solid;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }

.btn-info{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-align: center;
}


.fig-inline{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }


.page-header{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
 }

.row{
 padding-top: 50px;
 }

.list-inline{
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
}

li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px;
}

.footer{
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
 }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content=">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../portfolio/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-shader">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="page-header">
    <img src="../portfolio/images/ju-logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    <h6>Web Design & Development</h6>
</div>

<ul class="list-inline">

        <li><a href="....">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="....">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="....">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="....">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
        <div class="row">
<!-- About me col -->
            <div class="fig-inline">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="../portfolio/images/avatar.png" class="img-responsive">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Me</a>
                        </p>
                    </figure>
            </div>
<!-- Project col -->
            <div class="fig-inline">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="../portfolio/images/monitor.png" class="img-responsive">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Projects</a>
                            </p>
                    </figure>
            </div>
<!-- Contact col -->
            <div class="fig-inline">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="../portfolio/images/phone-call.png" class="img-responsive">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Contact</a>
                            </p>
                    </figure>
            </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <small>Copyright © 2018 Jake Ulicne </small>
    <small><div>Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/gregor-cresnar" title="Gregor Cresnar">Gregor Cresnar</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div></small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post all the required code (HTML and CSS) to enable us to reproduce the issue you are having.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Why not use a media query that gives you 100% height for desktop and then height auto for mobile

Comment: This example assumes all content should be placed on a background image that fills the browser window. I hope this helps move you in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/jakryrg9/

Comment: @Markie This did not work for me. The before pseudo was not displaying anything. I've updated post will full code.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Updated post will full code!

Comment: @Pete The media query also ended up cutting off the mobile view. I have updated the post with the full code to review!

Comment: Thanks. On my phone right now so if it hasnt been answered by the time I look at this on my laptop I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign 100vh height to .container-shader class, like this example:

```
.container-shader {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This worked when combined with a media query suggested by another user. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding vh to .container-shader class:

```
.container-shader{
 ...
 height: 100vh;
```

And a media query to stop the cut off on mobile resolutions:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
 .container-shader{
  height: auto;
 }
}
```